# Why do I get an error when I try to get data from "/api/products"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

I get an error when I try to get data from "/api/products"

```
function HomeScreen (props){

  const [products, setProduct] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
   const fetchData = async () => {
     const {data} = await axios.get('/api/products');
     setProduct(data);
   }
   fetchData();
   return () => {

   };
 }, [])
```

[image]

Comment: what is the error? it's possibly your server code that is *wrong*

Comment: import express from 'express';
import data from './data';

const app = express();

app.get("/api/products", (req, res) => {
  res.send(data.products);
});

app.listen(5000, () => { console.log("Server started at: http://localhost:5000") })

Comment: interesting comment ... if it's code it should be in the question

Comment: sorry..
It was my code from server.js

Comment: yes, and as such is not easily readable in a comment

Answer (score -1):

check if your API gets error during fetch or your API is running. It may cause because of wrong url too.